# Strange Bar Overlayed on Flex Interface

Tags: apache-flex, air, components, flash-builder

When I set my Flex application to run in FullScreen_Interactive, as soon as I click on a control this bar appears along the bottom of the screen.  It's quite obtrusive and has shown up on two different computers so far.

There's a lot of solid white underneath it and it covers at least 5-10% of the bottom of the screen, it blocks the controls also. I obviously never made/placed this thing, has anyone else come across this?

APPEND:

```
protected function windowedapplication1_applicationActivateHandler(event:AIREvent):void
        {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, stopesc);

            //Scale to resolution size
            var thisScreen:Screen = Screen.mainScreen;
            var newScaleX:Number = thisScreen.visibleBounds.width / 1019 * 0.98;
            var newScaleY:Number = thisScreen.visibleBounds.height / 680 * 0.98;
            var newScale:Number = Math.min(newScaleX,newScaleY,1.5);
            this.scaleX = newScale;
            this.scaleY = newScale;
            this.height = this.height * newScale;
            this.width = this.width * newScale;
            showStatusBar="false"

        }
```

Comment: unfortunately my rank is not high enough - though I will append some initialization code

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
showStatusBar="false"
```

in the WindowedApplication.

Comment: @Fuller - First off, 'showStatusBar="false"' is meant to be in MXML, not AS3.  ActionScript version is 'showStatusBar = false;'.  But still, you might be right and it's not the problem, since I already see another problem in your code.  Namely, you are both SCALING and RESIZING your window on fullscreen.  The 'width' and 'height' properties are changed when you scale, which means your code above is multiplying 2x newScale.  Also, can you try setting the 'backgroundColor' for the WindowedApplication to something other than white (default), just to check if you're just seeing the background.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for the late reply to this.  The status bar, when hidden, removes about half of the bar across the bottom of the screen. Now the rest of it I assume is a scaling issue.  I will look into that.  Instead of making the interface resolution independent, I merely decided to scale the contents to the screen size, causing this glitch.